# Connecting to SQL Server using PyQt

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5

How can I use Qt to connect to a SQL Server (developing on a Mac)

I've been trying to first follow this guide to install the ODBC driver but its just not working http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qodbc

On step 2 it says to run

`qmake -- ODBC_PREFIX=/usr/local/unixODBC`

I've actually changed that path to point to a fresh download of unixODBXC

`qmake -- ODBC_PREFIX=/Users/userx/Downloads/unixODBC-2.3.7`

The output from that ends up being

```
Running configuration tests...
Done running configuration tests.

Configure summary:

Qt Sql Drivers:
  DB2 (IBM) .............................. no
  InterBase .............................. no
  MySql .................................. no
  OCI (Oracle) ........................... no
  ODBC ................................... no
  PostgreSQL ............................. no
  SQLite2 ................................ no
  SQLite ................................. yes
    Using system provided SQLite ......... no
  TDS (Sybase) ........................... no

Qt is now configured for building. Just run 'make'.
Once everything is built, Qt is installed.
You should NOT run 'make install'.
Note that this build cannot be deployed to other machines or devices.

Prior to reconfiguration, make sure you remove any leftovers from
the previous build.
```

Then when I run `make sub-odbc` I get

```
> make sub-odbc
make: *** No rule to make target `sub-odbc'.  Stop.
```

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/userx/Qt/5.12.0/clang_64/bin
cd /Users/userx/Qt/5.12.0/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers
qmake -- ODBC_PREFIX=/Users/userx/Downloads/unixODBC-2.3.7
make sub-odbc
```

I'm following this exactly as instructions but it doesn't seem to work, any pointers or suggestions?

Comment: If you notice your exit says: `ODBC ................................... no`

Comment: Yes that's the point I need to compile it and place it in sqldrivers, I can't compile it that's what I'm asking

Answer (score 0):

I know it's pretty late, but try

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/userx/Qt/5.12.0/clang_64/bin
cd /Users/userx/Qt/5.12.0/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers

echo "" > config.cache
echo "" > config.log

qmake -- ODBC_PREFIX=/Users/userx/Downloads/unixODBC-2.3.7
make sub-odbc
```